# Adding object string to array using jq doesn't translate escape characters

Tags: bash, jq

I'm trying to add an object {...} to parent [...] using jq.

But the following

```json
parent="[]"


block=$(cat << EOF
{
    "block_id": "$block_id",
    "block_parent_id": "$block_parent_id",
    "current_index": 0,
    "child_sum": 0,
    "block_cidr": "",
    "block_size": "",
    "child_cidr": "",
    "child_size": "",
    "subnets": []
}
EOF
)

jq --arg ITEM "$block" '.+[$ITEM]' <<< "$parent"
```

gives

```json
[
  "{\n\t\"block_id\": \"\",\n\t\"block_parent_id\": \"\",\n\t\"current_index\": 0,\n\t\"child_sum\": 0,\n\t\"block_cidr\": \"\",\n\t\"block_size\": \"\",\n\t\"child_cidr\": \"\",\n\t\"child_size\": \"\",\n\t\"subnets\": []\n}"
]
```

As you can see escape characters like \n and \t are encoded literally. How do I add item to parent [] with escape characters properly translated (eg \n -> new line)?

Refer https://replit.com/@LoganLee7/jq-add-item-encodes-n-t#main.sh

Answer (score 1):

I've found the answer:

```
jq --arg ITEM "$block" '.+[$ITEM|fromjson]' <<< "$parent"
```

or

```
jq --argjson ITEM "$block" '.+[$ITEM]' <<< "$parent"
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is twofold:

1. You are handing JSON to `jq` using `--arg`, which expects text.  This means that `jq` will JSON-encode the given text into a string.  The `jq` utility has a separate option, `--argjson`, for when the passed data is a JSON document.
2. In the most general case, you don't want to inject shell variables into a JSON document without encoding their contents.  You do this by passing the variable's data to `jq` using `--arg`, or by using some other tool (like `jo`) which expects non-JSON input and produces JSON output.

- You also use `[]` unquoted, which would cause the shell to complain if it has the `failglob` (or equivalent, like `nomatch` in `zsh`) shell option set.  The `zsh` shell has its `nomatch` shell option set by default.

Your issue would be best solved by using `jq` to add the data directly to your existing document:

```bsh
jq \
        --arg block_id "$block_id" \
        --arg block_parent_id "$block_parent_id" \
        --argjson current_index 0 \
        --argjson child_sum 0 \
        --arg block_cidr "" \
        --arg block_size "" \
        --arg child_cidr "" \
        --arg child_size "" \
        '. += [ $ARGS.named | .subnets = $ARGS.positional ]' \
        --args \
        <<<"$parent"
```

In the above command, I create the object that I add to the exsisting list in `$parent` by using `$ARGS.named` for each plain (scalar) key-value pair. The value of `$ARGS.named` is an object with the keys and values taken from the `--arg` options and their values.  I then add the `subnets` array by using `$ARGS.positional`.  This value is the array of values after `--args` on the command line.  The `--args` option is required to be the last option on the command line, and the list is empty in the command above.

If you want to create the object that you add separately:

```bsh
to_add=$(
jq -n \
        --arg block_id "$block_id" \
        --arg block_parent_id "$block_parent_id" \
        --argjson current_index 0 \
        --argjson child_sum 0 \
        --arg block_cidr "" \
        --arg block_size "" \
        --arg child_cidr "" \
        --arg child_size "" \
        '[ $ARGS.named | .subnets = $ARGS.positional ]' \
        --args
)

jq --argjson block "$to_add" '. += $block' <<<"$parent"
```